# 日本語に違和感: メインサイトで質問中に右に表示されるヘルプ： 質問方法

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

メインサイトで質問を投稿中、タイトル入力欄にフォーカスがある時に、以下のヘルプが右に表示されます。

> 質問方法
>
> 質問はプログラミング関係ですか？
>
> 当サイトは意見交換向けより、回答ができる質問中心に作成しています。
>   詳細を含めて具体的に問題を説明し、今までの検討結果も共有してください。
>   当サイトについての質問なら、metaに聞いてください 。
>
> ヘルプ・センターを参考 »
>   質問の聞き方を参考 »

- 「質問方法」: 方法というよりガイドラインに近い
- 「質問はプログラミング関係ですか？」と聞かれても答えのもっていきようがなくて困る
- 「サイトは...作成しています」
- 「metaに聞いてください」
- 「...を参考」: 「参考ください」という言い方と同じような違和感があります

英語版

> How to Ask
>   Is your question about programming?
>   We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>   Provide details. Share your research.
>    If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
>   visit the help center »
>   asking help »

Answer (score 1):

> 質問するその前に
>
> このサイトはプログラミングに関するQ&Aを対象にしています。
>
> 単なる議論に終わらず、解決可能な質問を歓迎します。
>
> これまでに試したことや調べたことを含め、質問内容を詳しく書くことで回答がつきやすくなります。
>
> 使い方がわからないなど、このサイトそのものについての質問でしたら、[meta]で受け付けています。
>
> ヘルプセンターへ »
>   質問の手引き »